# Automatically synchronize files between PCs and Android without Internet

Tags: wi-fi, sync, windows, wifi-direct, shareit

I have two laptops. One has internet access while the other does not. Both laptops are in a remote location (one in the office and the other in the home). I have to download some files on a daily basis (3~7 files having 500MB~2000MB file size) for my office project and need these files in the home as well.

[image: Scenario]

I do not want to re-download these files in the home, so I use the following procedure:

1. Download file in Office Laptop
2. Copy in (Android) mobile (via SHAREit App)
3. Paste in the home Laptop (via SHAREit App)
4. Delete from Mobile
5. Delete from Office Laptop

**Is it possible to do all these steps automatically?**

This means, at the end of the day (before leaving my office) I just run a script that copy (latest) files on my mobile and delete these files from the office PC; when I reached home (from mobile) I run another script, which copies these (latest) files in my home PC and delete from mobile.

Comment: Possible in multiple ways. E.g. run `rclone` on all of the three devices. Or run `sshd`/`sftp` server on phone and clients on both PCs. Or even simple run a FTP server on phone temporarily. With all these options you can use a local WiFi network if available. Or phone's hotspot. No internet required.